# How / Can I use Asymptote, ams math and TikZ in a ConTeXt based document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, context, asymptote

My understanding is that Context has a pretty diverse core base load.  But I was curious if asymptote code blocks can be used in a context document?

I am used to calling packages at the beginning of a LaTex document but am unsure and have not found a good example of using either asymptote or ams math.

I am thinking the functionality of ams is included in the Context core but I cannot imagine that asymptote functionality is part of the context core.

It is my understanding that there is a TikZ module for Context.  When I did the setup I included all modules.  How do I verify (what command) what modules have been loaded as part of the Context setup?

Comment: »How do I verify (what command) what modules have been loaded as part of the Context setup?«  I don't understand this part of the question.  Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 9):

## Asymptote

How to use Asymptote was demonstrated by Aditya on the [mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/080581.html).

```
\usemodule[filter]

\defineexternalfilter
   [ASY]
   [
     filter={asy -tex "context" -outformat pdf
             -outname \externalfilteroutputfile},
     output=\externalfilterbasefile.pdf,
     cache=yes,
     readcommand=\ReadImage,
   ]

\define[1]\ReadImage{\externalfigure[#1]}

\starttext
   Testing if we can include an asymptote image
   \startplacefigure[location={here}, title={An Asymptote figure}]
     \startASY
       unitsize(1cm);
       draw((-.1,0) -- (2,0), arrow=Arrow(TeXHead));
       draw((0,-.1) -- (0,2), arrow=Arrow(TeXHead));
       draw((0,0) .. (1,1) .. (2,sqrt(2)));
     \stopASY
   \stopplacefigure
\stoptext
```

## TikZ

The TikZ manual describes the usage for all three common formats, LaTeX, Plain TeX, and ConTeXt.  Be aware that TikZ uses a different colour model than ConTeXt which can lead to strange interactions, see for example [this post on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086068.html).

[image]

## AMSmath

There is no `amsmath` for ConTeXt.  However, the ConTeXt core implements most of the major functionality for which you would use `amsmath` in LaTeX.

There is a great article by Aditya in the MAPS journal on how to emulate certain popular AMSmath constructs in ConTeXt.

> **Display Math in ConTEXt**
>
> *ConTEXt rehab for amsmath addicts*
>
> https://www.ntg.nl/maps/34/06.pdf

Comment: Henri how is   filter={asy -tex "context" -outformat pdf providing an asymptote process link into the document?  Is it because as long as I have the asymptote binary in the computer path this will give context the link it needs to use the asymptote processing functionality?

Comment: @TimC: see the documentation of the [filter module](https://github.com/adityam/filter/blob/master/README.md). Behind the scenes, the filter module writes the file to disk, runs the `filtercommand` on the file and then reads the output.